# Are two numbers, $a$ and $b$, uniquely determined by their addition $a+b$ and product $a b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm wondering whether for any two numbers, are their respective values uniquely determined by the output of their addition, and output of their product? For example if we knew $x = a+b$ and $y = a b$, would we always know $a$ and $b$? And if so, would this apply to more than two numbers?

Comment: Say $x=1$ and $y=-2$.  Then $a=2$ and $b=-1$ or $a=-1$ and $b=2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a+b=x$ and $ab=y$ then $a(x-a)=y$, which implies $a^2-xa+y=0$. This is a quadratic equation which has at most two complex solutions. They are given by $a_1=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4y}}{2}$ and $a_2=\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-4y}}{2}$. It doesn't matter which solution you will choose, you will get that the second solution equals to $b=x-a$. So yes, such $a$ and $b$ are unique up to switching between them.

Answer (score 2):

You know them up to permutation. That is, you can know the set $ \{a,b \} $ but not who specifically $ a,b $ are.

Indeed, with your notations, $ a,b $ are the only roots of the polynomial $ X^2 -xX + y = (X-a)(X-b) $.

This generalizes to any finite list of numbers $ (x_1,..., x_n) $ :  you can know it up to permutation from the knowledge of $ \displaystyle \sum_{i_0<...<i_k} x_{i_0}...x_{i_k} $ for $ k $ varying from $ 0 $ to $ n-1 $ because these are the coefficients of the polynomial $ (X-x_1)...(X-x_n) $ whose roots are precisely this list, up to permutation.

Comment: What’s nice about this approach is that by avoiding any explicit solving for $a,b$ we can be confident that there are no hidden singularities for special values of $a,b$, so this generalizes very cleanly.

Comment: @ErickWong : or special fields if we're interested in more general numbers. The accepted answer, for instance, doesn't deal wkth characteristic $ 2 $

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations in two unknowns.  Because one is quadratic, you expect two solutions, which are accounted for by swapping $a$ and $b$.

With more than two variables, you have fewer equations than unknowns, so expect an infinite number of solutions, though some may be complex.  As a real example, note that $$1+4+11=16\\ 1\cdot 4 \cdot 11=44$$, then if we want one number to be $2$ we just solve the above with sum of $14$ and product of $42$, getting 
$$2,7-\sqrt 7, 7+\sqrt 7$$
with the same sum and product

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intuitive way to see this. The description is long, but simple once you visualize it.

First, let's change symbols to the convention that $x,y$ are variables and $a,b$ are constants:

$$\begin{align}
  x+y & =a \\
  xy & =b
\end{align}
$$

Solve for $y$, so we can graph them:

$$\begin{align}
  &y=-x+a\\  &y=b\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
$$

The first equation is a line with gradient $-1$ (so it slopes diagonally right-down), with y-intercept at $a$, which could be positive or negative or zero.

The second equation is two curves, symmetrical over the diagonal line $y=x$, and also over the diagonal line $y=-x$. Perhaps it's easier to see in the original form $xy=b$: whatever values of $x,y$ make this equation true, swapping them is also makes it true.

If $b$ is positive, there's two curves, one in quadrant I (both $x,y$ are positive), and the other in quadrant III (both $x,y$ are negative). If $b$ is negative, the curves are in quadrants II and IV (only one of $x,y$ is negative). In all, $y$ is not defined at $x=0$.

Finally, the line and curves constrain $x,y$ to their intersection.

When $b$ is positive (curves in Quadrants I, III), the diagonal line might go between the curves, and there's no solution. Or, *just* touch one of the curves, and there's one solution. Or, it might intersect one of the curves twice. Because the curves are symmetrical over the diagonal line $y=x$, the intersections are the same values for $x,y$, but swapped.

If $b$ is negative (curves in Quadrants II, IV), the line always intersects both curves once. Because the curves are also symmetrical over the line $y=-x$, again the two intersections are the same values for $x,y$, just swapped.

The key thing about this proof is that there is a unique solution, just swapped. The swapping is secondary, but another way to see that swapping must give the same solution is that addition and multiplication are both commutative: $x+y=y+x$ and $xy=yx$.

PS: maybe I should have just drawn the graphs.